# como verifico si una consulta de sqlite esta vacia en java?

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite

estoy haciendo una aplicación para android con **java**, y no logro hacer funcionar un método para verificar si un usuario ya esta en uso.

```
public boolean existeUsuario(String pUser){
        this.seleccionarDatos("SELECT user FROM Usuarios WHERE user = '" + pUser + "'");

        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

La variable c es un cursor.

Comment: Qué es la variable `c` ?

Comment: La variable c es un cursor.